# Video Controls appears for few seconds when user tries to launch video

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm playing audio file from network ,when i launch the audio for fraction of second video controls appears and then it turns to audio control.I tried for `'IsAudioOnly'` property but result is same.

Following in my xaml code :

```
<MediaElement x:Name="EtextAudio" Visibility="Visible" AutoPlay="True" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Height="100" Width="400"
       Source="{Binding LinkObjectModel.LinkValue"/>
```

Comment: You should put your code here...where's your Xaml code?

Comment: Attached the xaml code

Comment: you should try this. EtextAudio.HasAudio.ToString();

Comment: not working?? is there anyway we can tell media element that this audio only ??